# Resuming a vim session I have accidentally disconnected from

Tags: vim, process, remote-access

I came across an unusual problem today,

I was using vim, had created a new alias in bash, and wanted to try it out.

So I ctrl-<kbd>z</kbd>, `exec bash` (I do this because I don't like nesting it with `bash`).

And my job has gone. And I now can't resume vim.

The only option I can think of is to kill vim and start a new session.

```
vim
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

```
exec bash
fg
```

**Edit**: This is *independent* of using screen/tmux.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider `reptyr`:

```
NAME
       reptyr - Reparent a running program to a new terminal

SYNOPSIS
       reptyr PID
```

Find vim's process id with `pidof vim` or `ps aux | grep vim`.

It is also possible to see the process id if you try to open a file which is still opened by vim. Using the shown pid you should be able to reattach to your previous session.

If you get an error:

```
Unable to attach to pid 12345: Operation not permitted
```

Ensure that the `ptrace scope` is set to `0` (instead of `1`):

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

After running `reptyr`, you may have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or another key to refresh the terminal (console) window.

Comment: Thanks, although this didn't work in this case, I ended up having to kill it. This is the solution I was looking for

Comment: This is **GREAT**. Now if I loose network connectivity, I can resume vim after logging in again without having to resort to killing vim and cleaning up with `vim -r`. Wish I could give more than one up-vote!

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch: If this is a regular problem, you should consider running your programs within tmux or GNU screen.

Comment: @Thor Thanks, I know about tmux and I "consider" it, but on average tend to forget / not bother :-)

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch: Me too, that's how I found reptyr :-)

Answer (score 9):

`vim -r {file}` is what you want, "r" for "Recovery mode". See `man vim`:

```
Recovery mode.  The swap file is used to recover a  crashed 
editing  session.   The  swap  file is a file with the same
filename as the text file with ".swp" appended.  See ":help
recovery".
```

Comment: yes, this is probably the best option, but I would like to have a way to reattach to the same session! something like emacs --daemon

Comment: This would work... but I still can't kill or reattach to my vim session which is still running
Just `-9`'d it...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use something like the 'screen' or 'tmux' utility to keep your terminal sessions going in the background.

Comment: I already do this, but the point is, I have no way to reattach to it, it was in a screen session, but I restarted my bash shell, and it didn't kill my vim

Comment: It would probably be a good idea, then, to add that information to your original question.

Comment: I thought it clear enough, considering the instructions I give to emulate it. I have edited for clarity. thanks :